# Run ResponsiveVoice speech on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, onload, responsivevoice

This works properly, it speaks the text area on click, but how can I change it to speak `onload`?

```
<script src="http://responsivevoice.org/responsivevoice/responsivevoice.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-git2.js"></script>

<textarea id="text" cols="45" rows="3"> HHHH</textarea>

<select id="voiceselection"></select>

<input onclick="responsiveVoice.speak($('#text').val(),$('#voiceselection').val());" type="button" value="Play" />
<br>
<button id="isPlaying">Playing:</button>
<p id="r">?</p>
```

Text area just says four letters now.

I imagine this is the key part, but can not fit it into anything properly to execute:

```js
responsiveVoice.speak($('#text').val(),$('US English Female').val());
```

I tried:

```js
var voicelist = responsiveVoice.getVoices();

var vselect = $("#voiceselection");

$.each(voicelist, function() {
  vselect.append($("<option />").val(this.name).text(this.name));
});

// Yours
$('#isPlaying').on('click', function() {
  $('#r').text(window.speechSynthesis.speaking)
})

$(document).ready(function() { //short code: $(function() { ... });
  responsiveVoice.speak($('#text').val(), $('US English Female').val());
});
```

```html
<script src="http://responsivevoice.org/responsivevoice/responsivevoice.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-git2.js"></script>

<textarea id="text" cols="45" rows="3">It reads this</textarea>

<select id="voiceselection"></select>
<script>
</script>

<input onclick="responsiveVoice.speak($('#text').val(),$('US English Female').val());" type="button" value="Play" />
```

But I get a "No voice found for: undefined" error.

Comment: `$('US English Female')` is not a valid **HTML Element**. 
`responsiveVoice.speak($('#text').val(), 'US English Female')`

Comment: like mentioned in the comments and an answer, the problem was not the voice selection (the api, and libs *should* fallback on a default) the problem was that the voices had not loaded yet.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Hook into the `OnVoiceReady` handler, then try to speak once the default voice, etc. is loaded:

```js
responsiveVoice.OnVoiceReady = function() {
  console.log("speech time?");
  responsiveVoice.speak($('#text').val());
};
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//responsivevoice.org/responsivevoice/responsivevoice.js"></script>

<textarea id="text" cols="45" rows="3">one two three</textarea>
```

Comment: why wont this run on iphone safari? also why does it stop working after after 4 or 5 refresh  after 10 seconds on android broswer?

Comment: Is this function to be deprecated? Its not in there API but it does work!

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for using ResponsiveVoice!

You should attach to the `OnReady` event using this code:

```
responsiveVoice.addEventListener("OnReady", myInitFunction);
```

as it's not enough to wait until page load. You need to wait until voices are loaded.

> why wont this run on iphone safari?

Apple prevents any speech to be initiated without a user action. So you would need to trigger speak() after a button click, for example.

> also why does it stop working after after 4 or 5 refresh after 10
>   seconds on android broswer?

ResponsiveVoice has some issues on Android devices. We're working on fixing it. We recommend using our latest release which you can find here:

https://code.responsivevoice.org/develop/responsivevoice.js

Answer (score 1):

Don't use inline event handling. Use abstracted events. It makes for easier to understand/read code.

```
$(document).ready(function() { //short code: $(function() { ... });
    responsiveVoice.speak($('#text').val(),$('#voiceselection').val());
});
```

The document ready event is triggered when the DOM is finished loading.

No jQuery version:

`window.onload`, using the new ES6 standard arrow function. No jQuery needed!

```
window.onload = () => {
    responsiveVoice.speak(document.getElementById("text").value, document.getElementById("voiceselection").value);
}
```

Comment: It's pretty safe to assume, since they are already using jQuery objects. But, I will add a vanilla answer :D

Comment: I think it's more than safe considering the OP's code includes a link to jQuery.. :D if anything the tag should be added.

Comment: this is not playing on load

Comment: it still requires a click

Comment: @JamesShelton are you just changing the onclick="" code?? because this needs to be included in a new script tag or as an external script, it wouldn't be a 1:1 replacement for the onclick contents.

Comment: I just copied and pasted his code into jsfiddle and I get "RV: ERROR: No voice found for: null" but it could be  my implementation

Comment: Be careful, onload waits for images and CSS to load.

Comment: little bit of inspection: http://jsfiddle.net/rlemon/q8b1z36f/ if you notice the log "RV: Voice support ready" attempting to use the library before it is ready fails (almost) silently. I imagine there is an event thrown from the lib you can listen for.

Comment: I added 'US English Female'

Comment: It will run one click, but it wont run onload

Answer (score 0):

According to the **[official site](http://responsivevoice.org/)**, the second argument must be a valid voice type, but in your example, the element **voiceselection** has no values, then the API fails. If you try with the default voice, the API will succeed!

```
var text = $('#text').val(),
    voice = $('#voiceselection').val();

//success
responsiveVoice.speak(text); //HHHH

//fails
responsiveVoice.speak(text, voice); //HHHH, ""

//Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'mappedProfile' of null(…)
```